# raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, odoo

I am trying to create a module for "Daily Transaction" and getting a `ValueError`

> ```
>     value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1028, in xmlid_lookup
>     raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
> ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: daily_transaction.action_daily_transaction" while parsing /home/odoo/odoo-dev/custom-addons/daily_transaction/daily_transaction_view.xml:11, near <menuitem action="action_daily_transaction" id="menu_action_daily_transaction" parent="menu_daily_transaction_root" sequence="20"/>
> ```

My file Structure: (One with Bold are my file names)

**__init__.py**

```
from import daily_transaction
```

**__manifest__.py**

```
{
        'name':'Daily Transaction Manager',
        'version':'1.0',
        'description':'**********************This app will keep the record of all the tansactions happening*********',
        'author':'Test',
        'data':['daily_transaction_view.xml'],
        'installable':True,
        'auto_install':False,
}
```

**daily_transaction.py**

```
from . import fields,osv

class daily_transaction(osv.osv):
        _name = 'daily.transaction'
        _description = 'Daily Transaction'
        _columns = {

                'subject': fields.char('Subject', size=128, required = True),
                'data' : fields.data('Date', required = True),
                'note': fields.text('Notes'),
                'amount': fields.float('Amount', required = True),
                'type' : fields.selection([
                        ('transport','Transport'),
                        ('household','Household'),
                        ('personal','Personal'),
                        ],
                        'Type', required = True),
                        }
```

**daily_transaction_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<odoo>
<data>

<!-- Main Menu Related Info -->        
<menuitem name="Daily Transaction" id="base.daily_transaction_root"            sequence="60"/>
<!-- Sub Menu Related Info -->       
<menuitem id="menu_daily_transaction_root" name="Daily Transaction"            parent="base.daily_transaction_root" sequence="1" /> 
<!-- Action Menu Related Info -->       
<menuitem action="action_daily_transaction" id="menu_action_daily_transaction" parent="menu_daily_transaction_root" sequence="20"/>

<!--Daily Transaction List View-->    
<record id="view_daily_transaction_tree" model="ir.ui.view">  <!-- here id is the external id for this tree view which must be unique and will be used for accessing this record -->
<field name="name">daily.transaction.tree</field> <!-- this will be our name of record in ir.ui.view -->        
<field name="model">daily.transaction</field>    <!-- this will map out tree view with our daily transaction model -->
<field name="arch" type="xml">           
 <!-- this will be our title of list/tree view -->            
<tree string="Daily Transaction">               
 <!-- these will automatically map table headers for our list view, so we’ll select out column names of our model here -->               
 <field name="name"/>              
 <field name="date"/>              
 <field name="type"/>               
<field name="amount"/>                   
</tree>       
</field>
</record>


<!--Daily Transaction Form View-->    
<record id="view_daily_transaction_form" model="ir.ui.view">        
<field name="name">daily.transaction.form.view</field>        
<field name="model">daily.transaction</field>        
<field name="arch" type="xml">            
<!-- this will be our title of list/tree view -->            
<form string="Daily Transaction" version="7.0">                
<group>                    
<field name="name"/>                    
<field name="date"/>                    
<field name="type"/>                     
<field name="amount"/>                     
<field name="note"/>                                   
</group>             
</form>        
</field>    
</record>

<record id="action_daily_transaction" model="ir.actions.act_window">        
<field name="name">Daily Transaction</field>        <!-- name of action -->
<field name="res_model">daily.transaction</field>        <!-- this action will be mapped to model specified -->
<field name="view_type">form</field>        
<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>        <!-- these are type of view our module will show for our daily transaction mode  -->
<field name="search_view_id"  eval="False"/>        <!-- here we specify id of our search view -->
<field name="context">{}</field>        
<field name="help">Create new daily transaction.</field>    <!-- help text for our model -->
</record>

</data>
</odoo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is giving this error because you are using action before it is created, So first you have to define your action and then you can use it.

So you should try as following:

```
<record id="action_daily_transaction" model="ir.actions.act_window">        
    <field name="name">Daily Transaction</field>        <!-- name of action -->
    <field name="res_model">daily.transaction</field>        <!-- this action will be mapped to model specified -->
    <field name="view_type">form</field>        
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>        <!-- these are type of view our module will show for our daily transaction mode  -->
    <field name="search_view_id"  eval="False"/>        <!-- here we specify id of our search view -->
    <field name="context">{}</field>        
    <field name="help">Create new daily transaction.</field>    <!-- help text for our model -->
</record>

<menuitem action="action_daily_transaction" id="menu_action_daily_transaction"
parent="menu_daily_transaction_root" sequence="20"/>
```

Comment: It did solve that error, but now it has an error of 
Model not found : daily.transaction